Read files from an archive which contains another archive
I'm using SharpCompress and trying to read files which are archived in a 7z archive.
Now I got stuck at a point where my 7z archive contains another zip or 7z, which contains the file I want to read. Is there a way how the read the content of a file, which is archived multiple times without extracting the archives on disk?
Just for test purpose, I have my simple method which should write me all the entries from the archive.
namespace TestArchiv
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frmReference = this;
            try
            {
                processArchive(@"C:\temp\temp.zip");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToBox(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void processArchive(string archivePath)
        {
            using (var archive = SevenZipArchive.Open(archivePath))
            {
                foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
                {

                    if (entry.ToString().Contains("7z"))
                    {
                        using (SevenZipArchive inner2 = SevenZipArchive.Open(entry.OpenEntryStream()))
                        {

                            foreach (var entry2 in inner2.Entries)
                            {
                                WriteToBox(entry2.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    WriteToBox(entry.ToString());
                    
                }
            }
        }

        public void WriteToBox(string text)
        {

            //frmReference.TextBox1.Clear();
            frmReference.TextBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + text);

        }
}
}

When I try to run this, I'm getting
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at SharpCompress.IO.ReadOnlySubStream.get_Length()
   at SharpCompress.IO.SourceStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
   at SharpCompress.IO.SourceStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
   at SharpCompress.IO.NonDisposingStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive.LoadFactory(Stream stream)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive.LoadEntries(IEnumerable`1 volumes)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.AbstractArchive`2..ctor(ArchiveType type, SourceStream sourceStream)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive..ctor(SourceStream sourceStream)
   at SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive.Open(Stream stream, ReaderOptions readerOptions)
   at TestArchiv.MainWindow.processArchive(String archivePath) in C:\Users\martin.toman\source\repos\TestArchiv\TestArchiv\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 56
   at TestArchiv.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\martin.toman\source\repos\TestArchiv\TestArchiv\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 38

Just to clarify, I'm processing C:\temp\CaCCdm30_2.7z which contains another CaCCdm30.7z
I was able to solve this problem for Zip files using the ZipFile class from C#, but I need to make it work for other archive types, so I went for SharpCompress.
This worked for zip files:
public void processArchive(ZipArchive archive)
 {
     foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
     {
         string fileName = entry.ToString();
         //WriteToBox(fileName);
         if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(".zip"))

         {
             ZipArchive innerArchive = new ZipArchive(entry.Open());
             processArchive(innerArchive);
         }
         else 
         .....
      }
}

EDIT: I added the complete code

I'm not overly familiar with SharpCompress, but I think your problem is that you're trying to SevenZipArchive.Open the file name (not the path). Even if it were the path, it would probably not work. Try with SevenZipArchive.Open(entry.OpenEntryStream())

I cant find any easy to read documentation for SharpCompress, but I would expect it to work similar to ZipArchive, i.e. there should be some method on the entry to open a Stream, if there is not, you might need to save the entry to a temporary file. Note that you should dispose opened streams after use.

@MindSwipe That's good point. I've tried with the stream, but now it fails with
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.    at SharpCompress.IO.ReadOnlySubStream.get_Length()    at SharpCompress.IO.SourceStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)    at SharpCompress.IO.SourceStream.set_Position(Int64 value)    at SharpCompress.IO.NonDisposingStream.set_Position(Int64 value)    at SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive.LoadFactory(Stream stream)    at SharpCompress.Archives.SevenZip.SevenZipArchive.LoadEntries(IEnumerable1 volumes)
.....`

That error tells me that you're trying to seek in the stream somehow, which is not shown in the code in your question. If you want to, you can [edit] your question and add your full code giving this error.

Thanks for the reply, I posted the complete code above
